# How to allow only specific pages to be included

Tags: php

Yesterday I asked a question about how to include files passed in via the URL, and someone give me this:

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])){
  include($_GET['file'].'.php');
}
```

But one of the answers told me to do something with this to avoid possible attacks from hackers or something like that. The problem is that I don't understand how to do it myself.

He said I should do something like this:

```
$pages_array=('home','services','contact').
```

And then check the GET var:

```
if(!in_array($_GET['page'], $pages_array) { die(); }
```

What does this do, and how do I integrate it into my original code above?

Comment: My question is How to modify the first code to make it work, and where to put these $page_array-s, i know this is a stupid question but i realy dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is looking for a `file` parameter in the URL, and then including whatever file was passed in. So if somebody goes to your PHP page and adds `?file=something.txt` to the URL, you'll include the contents of `something.txt` in your output.

The problem with this is that anybody can manually modify the URL to try to include whatever file they want - letting them see files on your system that should be private.

The solution is to have a list of allowed filenames, like this:

```
$pages = array('home', 'services', 'contact');
```

And then before you include the file, check that it's one of the allowed filenames first.

```
$pages = array('home', 'services', 'contact');
if (isset($_GET['file'])){
    if (!in_array($_GET['file'], $pages_array)) {
        exit('Not permitted to view this page');
    }
    include($_GET['file'].'.php');
}
```

We're using a PHP **[`array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)** to define the list of allowed pages, checking if our page is in the list with the **[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** function, and then stopping all script execution if it's not in the list with the **[`exit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)** function.

Answer (score 1):

The code checks the `GET` information passed from the browser to your PHP page by making sure that the page name is present in your `$pages_array`.

As long as you list all of the pages in your `$pages_array`, the code will execute. If the page is not in your array list, then it will `die` and not be executed.

When using `GET` it is always beneficial to validate the code sent in this way, as arbitrary statements can be sent and executed without validation.

The code, in this instance, is being validated - so you have taken the necessary steps; as long as there is nothing more to the code that you haven't submitted.

**Correct code**

```
$pages_array=array('home','services','contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your own question...

Except this line becomes...

```
$pages_array=array('home','services','contact');
```

Instead of what you had...

```
$pages_array=('home','services','contact').
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//change the variable array declaration
$newArray = array('home','services','contact');
```

Just do an else statement in your if like

```
 else { 
     //include your file
     include($_GET['page'].'.php');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Your syntax for an array definition is wrong, but also why `die()` if `$_GET['file']` is not set? would it not be better if you reverted to a default so as to fail silently.

Using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<?php
$pages_array = array('home','services','contact');

if(isset($_GET['file']) && in_array($_GET['file'], $pages_array)){
    include($_GET['file'].'.php');
}else{
    include('home.php');
}
?>
```

Or even using [switch()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) with hard coded values.

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : 'home';
switch($page){
    case "home"     : include($page.'.php'); break;
    case "services" : include($page.'.php'); break;
    case "contact"  : include($page.'.php'); break;

    default:
        include('home.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$pages=array('home','services','contact');

if(isset($_GET['page']))

{


$page=$_GET['page'];

if(!in_array($page,$pages)) 

{

die ('');


}

else {

include($page.'.php');

}
 }
```

So, your links will look like:

`yoursite.com/index.php?page=home`  -> with this tool:

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

you can make nicer URL's.

Comment: Why down vote? I have suggested this solution to OP, and that's why i answered, after all... I would like explanation, thanks.