# Security when using include

Tags: php, security, include

Good afternoon everyone, I am developing a page and as far as it goes it has an index.php and when I want to go to a certain tab(eg:contact), I include it with php so that when the user goes to index.php?tab=contact, it includes contact.php... However, I am aware of the security breaches this method has and I was wondering if you could help me. I was thinking of maybe limiting the files which can be included to the current folder so that the user cannot access files in the main directory. I was also thinking of using iframes but I don't like them so I would rather not use them. 
What do you think is the best/more secure method?
 Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Your question is either unclear or too broad. A little bit of example with simple code could have avoided the confusion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266766/how-to-allow-only-specific-pages-to-be-included

Answer (score 2):

The insecure way to do it is to include whatever the user wants to include

```
include $input_from_user;  // /etc/passwd?
```

The secure way to include a file based on an input parameter is to check for expected values.
(pseudocode)

```
switch($input_from_user) {
case "contents": include contents.php; break;
case "foo":      include foo.php; break;
default:         showLoginPrompt(); break; // or some other safe action
}
```

Comment: What do you think is a more secure method, this one or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266766/how-to-allow-only-specific-pages-to-be-included

Comment: The two solutions are equivalent.  The important thing in both is that you are specifically deciding what files can be included in the page, and under what conditions, on the server; you are not allowing the client to choose which page to include.